# Why is array not added to PHP class' property?

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm new to OOP PHP and have been following Laracasts OOP Bootcamp. I have reached a certain part of the tutorial where I'm having trouble. I have the following file (ignore that conventions were not followed, as it is the learning phase):

```
<?php
class Person
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Staff
{
    protected $members = [];

    public function __constructor($members = [])
    {
        $this->members = $members;
    }

    public function add(Person $person)
    {
        $this->members[] = $person;
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }
}

class Business
{
    protected $staff;

    public function __construct(Staff $staff)
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
    }

    public function hire(Person $person)
    {
        $this->staff->add($person);
    }

    public function getStaffMembers()
    {
        return $this->staff->members();
    }
}

$jeffrey = new Person('Jeffrey Way');

$staff = new Staff([$jeffrey]);

$laracasts = new Business($staff);
$laracasts->hire(new Person('Jane Doe'));

var_dump($laracasts->getStaffMembers());
```

Unfortunately, the var_dump is only giving me one staff member:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Person)#4 (1) {
    ["name":protected]=>
    string(8) "Jane Doe"
  }
}
```

I have tried adding `[]` to the line `$this->members = $members;` under Staff class but it's still giving me the same output. I've also double checked the files, I should be expecting two members instead of one.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct except for one line - the constructor for the class `Staff` is defined incorrectly. Replace

```
public function __constructor($members = [])
```

with

```
public function __construct($members = [])
```

Because of this mistake, the line `$staff = new Staff([$jeffrey]);` has no effect to the initialization of your internal `$members` array.